# Should the owner of a question be notified when the question get edited?

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications

I just found out that one of my question, created in April 2009, was edited, March 2010, and transformed into wiki by someone else.

Thing is, that question is not a wiki and I didn't noticed it until now, got a badge today for it.

what should I do, rolling it back until it's not a wiki anymore or just ignore it and move on?

since It seem impossible to remove a wiki flag(from comments), it mean anyone can go in any question and transform them into wiki and the owner can do nothing about it? I'm the only one seeing an issue here?

Comment: Just a note, though, you cannot actually rollback a post away from Community Wiki status. Once assigned, it is irrevocable.

Comment: @ccornet... great to know thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your edit. Also, in a few minutes, you should get a notification that I edited your question here (it may be visible in the Revisions tab already, even if the envelope at the top hasn't turned red yet).

Comment: @Jon Seigel, I see it now, it's not in the summary, I have to click on revision to see it. this is why I might have missed it.

Comment: If you see a pattern of systematic editing-to-make-CW abuse, flag one of the posts for moderator attention and explain. They can caution and/or box the users. To date we haven't had much trouble with this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post owners are already notified when a post (question or answer) is edited.

On your Recent Activity page (click the envelope at the top), these edits show up in the Revisions tab.

Also, just to note, once a question or answer goes into community-wiki mode, that cannot be undone through any means. Questions and answers are automatically converted to community-wiki mode under certain conditions -- please [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for all the details.